# Can we added changing image/text on android app

Tags: android

Is there a way in android app that we can add some text or image and we can change that dynamically without adding new version. Like we have this text: Today's deal is: 1
then in a week if i want that text to show as: Today's deal is: 2. 
Is there a way to do this, for an app which does not have a server and is stand alone app.

Comment: No server and no application updates?  How do you expect to get new information to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text or image can be altered during run time; so how you choose to change that is up to you. You would have a simply switch statement depending on the day of the week for your specific example.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.yourxml.name);
tv.setText("Monday!");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of to achieve this is by writing a long value in the shared preferences for a Date object. Each time you start the application we will check if it's been 1 day since the value was saved. Also maintain the different string you want to display as string array in the resources.

I hope it helps...